# Promise - On error resume - multiple api calls in redux

Tags: asynchronous, redux, promise, redux-thunk

I am using redux / thunk to make async calls and use promise to resolve them.

Everything works fine but I am trying to figure out a way to resume on error (even if one api call fails).

**Initial Load (Server side rendering)**

```
export const initialLoad = () => {
    return dispatch => Promise.all([
        dispatch(loadResults()),
        dispatch(loadGroups()),
    ]).catch(function (err) {

    });
};
```

**Functions:**

```
function loadGroups() {
    return dispatch =>
    fetch(
        url
    ).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (json) {
        dispatch(setGroupData(json))
});

function loadResults() {
    return dispatch =>
    fetch(
        url
    ).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (json) {
        dispatch(setResultData(json))
});
```

It there a way to resume rest of the calls even though one of the api calls fails?

Comment: Do you have the full code you are using where you would want to handle the error?

Comment: You can wrap each of the `fetch` call in a new Promise that never reject

Comment: According to your code snippet, your following requests DEPEND on result of previous request (they use 'json' output). So if the first request fails, how are you going to make the other one without data? :) If data is not critical, you could just move second request out of the promise